# How can I send a paper cut command using my web app?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a web app that prints out several receipts. I need to cut every consecutive receipt that follows. Is there a way somehow to embed the paper cut command in my HTML template?
Like a `<br>`

Thanks.

**UPDATE : ESC/POS Commands to cut paper**
[image]

**SUGGESTED SOLUTIONS :**

1. Convert a byte array (printer commands) to string and send it with the window.open(urlString).
2. After some research i found the jZebra applet. This will work for me! I can now
   send printer commands from browser to physical thermal printer on network address.
   http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/

Comment: What character(s) does your printer interpret as a paper cut command?

Comment: @tomfanning i updated the post with the esc commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found the jZebra applet. This will work for me! I can now send printer commands from browser to physical thermal printer on network address. http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/